# selinium python ie error - Browser zoom

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to python.I get this error when i execute the below code

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="<my IE DrIVER LOCATION>\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line
55, in __init__
desired_capabilities=capabilities)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 87, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 136, in start_session
'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 196, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 181, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launchi
ng Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 94%. It should be set to 100%
```

I have seen some links.But i couldnt find any for python.Can anyone help me out with how i can programatically solve this

Answer (score 1):

Change zoom level to 100% of your IE browser. you can do it by clicking on the gear icon that located at the top right corner of browser.